# Status 500 error when adding a large PDF to a zip file in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pdf, zip

When a user uploads an XML file to the website, they can click a Download Bundle PDF button (which has the RequestMapping of /bundle/{bundleId}/data.zip) to see their individual notices bundled up in a PDF file contained within a zip file. However, it's been discovered that when the user tries to upload an XML file containing a very large notice, and then clicks on the Download Bundle PDF button, the server responds with a status of 500 and it's not possible to download the zip file. At the moment we're using a byte array approach and writing the output to a ZipOutputStream. For large files, I've read that it is better to use a stream instead of a byte array. I have implemented the following code, but it's still returning a status 500 error when trying to download a large file.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bundle/{bundleId}/data.zip", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @Secured({GroupRoleNames.ROLE_PLACE_NOTICE})
  public void getNoticePdf(@PathVariable String bundleId, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    try {
      OutputStream output = httpResponse.getOutputStream();
      BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(output);
      ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
      httpResponse.setHeader("X-Robots-Tag", "noindex,follow");
      httpResponse.setContentType("application/zip");
      httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition:", "inline; filename=bundle_" + Math.random() + ".zip");
      httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-control:", "private");
      getBundlePdfAsZip(bundleId, zos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      if (e instanceof DataNotFoundException) {
        throw new DataNotFoundException(e);
      } else {
        logger.error(" error during print pdf for a single notice ", e);
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
      }
    }
  }

@Override
  public void getBundlePdfAsZip(String bundleId, ZipOutputStream zos) throws IOException {
    Set<String> noticeIds = new HashSet<String>();
    final BundleMetadataVO bundleMetadata = getBundleMetadata(bundleId);
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(bundleMetadata.getValidNoticeIds())) {
      throw new DataNotFoundException("Required Parameters Missing or Search fetched zero Results");
    }
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    noticeIds = bundleMetadata.getValidNoticeIds();
    for (String noticeId : noticeIds) {
      String supplierId = getSupplierId(noticeId);
      if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(supplierId) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(supplierId)) {
        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(supplierId + "_" + noticeId + ".pdf");
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
      } else {
        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(noticeId + "_" + ".pdf");
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
      }
      String uri = configurationProfileServices.quartzContextUri() + String.format(SINGLE_PDF_URI, noticeId);

      final File ret = File.createTempFile("download", "tmp");
      File file = restTemplate.execute(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, clientHttpResponse -> {
        StreamUtils.copy(clientHttpResponse.getBody(), new FileOutputStream(ret));
        return ret;
      });

      HttpHeaders headers = restTemplate.headForHeaders(uri);
      long contentLength = headers.getContentLength();

      restTemplate.execute(
          uri,
          HttpMethod.GET,
          clientHttpRequest -> clientHttpRequest.getHeaders().set(
              "Range",
              String.format("bytes=%d-%d", file.length(), contentLength)),
          clientHttpResponse -> {
            StreamUtils.copy(clientHttpResponse.getBody(), new FileOutputStream(file, true));
            return file;
          });
          
    }
    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();
  }
```

Do I need to write the contents of the file back to the ZipOutputStream, and if so, how can we do this? This is the code we had previously, when using the byte array approach:

```
byte[] pdfBody = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, byte[].class);
zos.write(pdfBody);
```

The stack trace from the logs is as follows. Interestingly, it shows a 404 error in the logs, but a 500 error in the Chrome Developer Tools console.

```
2021-10-11 11:49:50.829 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG u.c.g.dao.rest.RestContentDAO - loading document :: uri = /notice/5218192/version/1/supplier-id :: httpEntity = <{Cookie=[SessionID=null], Content-Type=[text/xml]}>
2021-10-11 11:49:50.906 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] ERROR u.c.g.a.c.BundleSummaryController -  error during print pdf for a single notice
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
        at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:775)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:728)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:684)
        at uk.co.getBundlePdfAsZip(NoticesBundleServiceImpl.java:334)
        at uk.co.BundleSummaryController.getNoticePdf(BundleSummaryController.java:248)
        at uk.co.BundleSummaryController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e2e72224.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:69)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
        at uk.co.BundleSummaryController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$851a488.getNoticePdf(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at uk.co.UpdateSavedRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(UpdateSavedRequestFilter.java:43)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at uk.co.auth.PreAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(PreAuthFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at uk.co.auth.BasicAuthModificationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthModificationFilter.java:38)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:146)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Error 500 means a server side error, there must be the stacktrace in the server logs. please post it.

Comment: @pleft I have added the stack trace to the end of the question. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't properly handle the exception near the place where it occurs, it is possible that the default handling turns it into 500. Your client is telling you: 404 ("I have not found something"), but the default exception handler tells: 500 ("Internal Server Error", "The server screwed the exception handling"). This is just my wild guess why you see 404 in the log but 500 outside. And your code near `restTemplate.execute()` is apparently missing any error handling.